# What happens when an exception is thrown from a filter after the servlet completes?

Tags: http, servlets, jersey, servlet-filters

I am working on a service hosting several REST API using Java Servlet.

The Servlet uses annotations provided by `javax.ws.rs` to define the API's URL, HTTP method, etc. So one of them may look like as follows:

```
@Path("root")
@Service
public class MyClass {
    @Path("path")
    @Get
    @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseObject myAction() { ... }
}
```

I also have a filter that due to some bug, could throw an exception after executing the servlet. So it behaves as follows:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        throws new Exception();
    }
}
```

The web.xml contains following definition: (not complete, just those I think might be relevant)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>myorg.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

When I call this API using different approaches, I get different results.

1. Using Jersey client and get as string

   ```
   WebResource resource = client.resource("https://my-service/root/path");
   ClientResponse response = resource.get(ClientResponse.class);
   String s = response.getEntity(String.class);
   ```

This will give me below error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:565)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:609)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:696)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3393)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.readFromAsString(ReaderWriter.java:171)
at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.readFromAsString(ReaderWriter.java:157)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.readFromAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:114)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.readFrom(StringProvider.java:73)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.readFrom(StringProvider.java:58)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634)
```

2. Using Jersey client but de-serializing the JSON response into an object

   ```
   WebResource resource = client.resource("https://my-service/root/path");
   ClientResponse response = resource.get(ClientResponse.class);
   ResponseObject result = response.getEntity(ResponseObject.class);
   ```

This will return successfully and the resulting `ResponseObject` contains correct content.

3. Call this API using HTTP tool Postman. This will also return status 200 and correct response body.
4. Call the API using .Net core library RestSharp

   ```
   var restClient = new RestClient("https://my-service/");
   var request = new RestRequest("/root/path", method);
   var response = restClient.Execute(request);
   ```

This will fail with following error:

```
The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingReadStream.ReadAsyncCore(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.HttpContentReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at RestSharp.Extensions.MiscExtensions.ReadAsBytes(Stream input)
at RestSharp.Http.ProcessResponseStream(Stream webResponseStream, HttpResponse response)
at RestSharp.Http.ExtractResponseData(HttpResponse response, HttpWebResponse webResponse)
at RestSharp.Http.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
```

**My question is:**
What happened to my HTTP response in this case and why different clients behaved differently ? I guess when `MyClass.myAction` completed, the serialized return object `ResponseObject` was already sent to the client. However, when the control was given back to `MyFilter`, an error was thrown. This must have had some impact on the HTTP response, but what ? And why would this by observed in some cases by some client but ignored by others ?

It's quite easy for me to fix the bug itself - to not throw exception in the filter. But I want to understand more about what happened underneath and appreciate any help.